# Symfony2 form: set default options depending on form value

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using Symfony2 framework (in particular, Symfony 2.7). My question is related to form building.

I have an entity named **place**, that can be associates to many other entities of my project. So, I created a custom form type that can be reused in many parts of my application.

```
class PlacesType extends AbstractType
{

    private $security_context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $security_context)
    {
        $this->security_context = $security_context;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $user = $this->security_context->getToken()->getUser();

        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Places',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($user)
            {
                return $repository->queryPlacesForUser($user);
            },
        ));

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity' ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'places';
    }
}
```

Fact is, places can be soft-removed (I set a *deleted* flag inside the class). So, new entities can be associated only to active places, while old entities can maintain their association with a now-deleted place.

For this reason, I want that the **queryPlacesForUser** function returns only *active* places, unless the place was already being associated to the parent's form data.
Something like this:

```
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // ...

        $currdata = $this->getForm()->getData(); // pseudo-code, this does not work

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Places',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($user)
            {
                return $repository->queryPlacesForUser($user, $currdata);
            },
        ));

    }
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to get current data from the options resolver. It is possible to retrieve current data inside the form's **buildForm** function, however it is not possible to set form options inside of it.

Is there a way I can set form default options using form passed data?

Comment: Would you be willing to *inject* the needed configuration data at that point in your code where you're using this custom form type?

Comment: No, I thought about it, but you would lose the benefits of having a shared form type.

Comment: Honestly, I think that's your only option. And it issn't much different from injecting the form data issn't it? I'll add an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have access to the form data inside `configureOptions`. With the added constraint that you only want to *pre/reconfigure* an extended type, I think, the only option is to extract the needed configuration to the place where this custom form type is used. E.g.:

**Usage**:

```
<?php

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->builder->add('place', PlacesType::class, [
        'only_active' => false // <- this is the *external* configuration
    ]);
}
```

**In `PlacesType`**:

```
<?php

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Places',
        'only_active' => true, // <- this is the *default* configuration

        // note the extra closure, this gives you access to the *resolved* options.
        'query_builder' => function (Options $options) { 
            return function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($options) {
                return $repository->queryPlacesForUser(
                    $this->security_context->getToken()->getUser(),
                    $options['only_active']
                );
            };
        },
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your answer (I passed directly the current place within the options), but I still do not like it very much. I had to modify more or less 20 forms where I was using my _places_ form type, and other entities of my project could behave in the same way. I would prefer a more scalable solution.

Comment: @Alberto I understand and have hit that specific *road block* myself a number of times. The problem really only arises from the fact that you want to change the defaults of the extended type based on underlying data. Till today, I haven't found a better solution, though I would really like to see one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an event listener like so :

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $form = $event->getForm();
    //check your data here and add the fields you want accordingly

$field = $builder->get('fieldToModify');         // get the field
$options = $field->getOptions();            // get the options
$type = $field->getType()->getName();       // get the name of the type
$options['label'] = "Login Name";           // change the label
$builder->add('fieldToModify', $type, $options); // replace the field
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not trying to add children to the form, but to set the options of current one.